# How to select one list element from an ordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of video titles. They are clickable links. They are arranged in an ordered list.

```
function showResults(results) {
    var html = '';
    html = "<ol>";
        $.each(results, function(index,value) {
        html += '<li><a data-video-type="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + value.id.videoId + '?autoplay=1"><img src="'  +value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' + value.snippet.title + '</a>)</li>';        });
        html += "</ol>";
        $('#results').html(html);
});
```

I can assign an id of videoChoice to ol, li, or a. I get an element by it's id tag like this:

```
"play number *val" : function(val) {
        var test = document.getElementById('videoChoice');
        test.click();

}
```

If the id is assigned to li or a, I can use the voice command and the video will play. Problem is, this method returns one specific video in the list. So I moved my id tag to the ol. This returns the full ordered list. Problem is I can't figure out how to select a list element by index number. I know how to select an element from an array by index number, for example, but I seem to need a different method here.

So how does one select a list element from an ordered list?

**SOLUTION**

As mentioned in the answers, the .eq() Jquery method is a good way to do this. I implemented the method, but had to also specify that it was a link by adding 'a'. This made it clickable.

```
"play number *val" : function(val) {
        var $ol = $('#videoChoice');
        var li = $ol.find('a','li').eq(val).click();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to select a list element by index number

If this is your issue, you can easily select  a list element using jquery [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method

eg: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ssilas777/atg5m6ym/1949/)

```
  var firstList =  $('ul#id').find('li').eq(0);
```

Comment: This was a great tool for the job, thanks for pointing that out. I added an 'a' to make it explicit that I was working with a link. This made it clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to select by index, check this out:

https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

You can select by index using the eq selector, so if you're trying to select the third item on the list, the selector would be as follows:

```
var Selection = $('li:eq(2)');
```

A JSFiddle for your convenience.

https://jsfiddle.net/tyatm27b/